# Creating an Executable / Deploying a Project with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, executable, deploying

So I have a project, written in VB.NET, that I deployed a couple months ago. When deploying the project, there came 3 file groups. There was the .application file, the setup.exe file, and the Application Files folder. From what I could tell, and through testing, it appears all 3 of these need to remain in the same location forever in order to be able to run the program without reinstalling every time. How do I make this more compact so that all 3 of these files/folders are in one, appear to be one, and don't cause problems when they aren't in the same location? It appears that the Application Files folder contains a manifest file as well as some other stuff, so it makes sense to me that one would need these files all in the same location, but it makes it difficult for the end user to use when they have to leave everything EXACTLY where it was left. No customization (new folders, etc) allowed, or the program doesn't run.

Comment: Are you using click-once deployment?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't use external .dlls or get use of the Settings File then the only file that you need will be the .exe file. Nothing else.

Comment: `When you don't use external .dlls` any external file for that matter. It is possible to have a txt, xml, etc. with copy to output directory set, which is used by the program. But yea, the dev should know what is required for the program to run.